# Subtle meanings of the noun 'stole', or am I reading too much in to it?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns

I'm referring to the item of clothing.  Not theft.

The definitions and descriptions that I've been able to find for the word 'stole' all have some indication of religious context.  It always seems to be made to specifications determined for religious reasons, or decorated with religious symbols, or worn only by individuals specifically designated for religious roles (especially, but not always, leaders), or only worn for specific religious ceremonies, etc.  Nowhere did I find any explanation of the word 'stole' that did not have some religious aspect.

Would an otherwise identical article of clothing, but without any religious connotation, still be called a 'stole', or is there another word for this item of clothing when no religious context is attributed to it?

Comment: I'm surprised that you have not found the definition of 'a woman's shoulder scarf' in addition to the ecclesiastical garment. This is usually wrapped round like  a shawl. The priest's stole is worn round the neck with the ends hanging; I can't imagine anyone wearing an _identical_ garment for any other reason than religious ceremonial.

Comment: Indeed, when I was young (1970s) my grandmother wore a fox stole, complete with tail, paws and head.

Comment: I don't know that I've ever heard of anything that wasn't a fur scarf referred to as a stole. *Mink stole* is my immediate mental association.

Comment: It's a straightforward Latin word, denoting a common Roman garment. Since then, its meaning has changed with the styles. So, what else is new?

Answer (score 4):

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stole) defines stole as:

> a long wide scarf or similar covering worn by women usually across the shoulders.

A woman’s stole

[image: a stole]

(Duemme.com)

A religious stole

[image]

(Holyart.com)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as in a woman's apparel, a **stole**. **[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/190712?rskey=UtwHX4&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)**

> 3. A woman's fur or feather garment, something in the shape of an ecclesiastical stole, worn over the shoulders and hanging down nearly
>      to the feet.

Is there anything more elegant than the image of a woman dressed in a long stole?  The image of a these stoles evoke a sense of elegance, timeless sophistication, and graceful style.

Answer (score 1):

**[Shawl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawl)**, Wikipedia.

> A **shawl** (from Persian: lang-Urdu شال‎ *shāl*, which may be from Hindi: दुशाला duśālā, ultimately from Sanskrit: शाटी śāṭī) is a simple item of clothing, loosely worn over the shoulders, upper body and arms, and sometimes also over the head. It is usually a rectangular or square piece of cloth, which is often folded to make a triangle, but can also be triangular in shape. Other shapes include oblong shawls.

[...]

> **Stole**
>
> A stole is a woman's shawl, especially a formal shawl of expensive fabric, used around the shoulders over a party dress or ball gown. A stole is narrower than a typical shawl and of simpler construction than a cape; it is a length of a quality material, wrapped and carried about the shoulders or arms. Lighter materials such as silk and chiffon are simply finished, that is, cropped, hemmed, and bound; heavier materials such as fur and brocade are often lined as well.
>
> A stole can also be a fur or set of furs, usually fox, worn as a stole with a suit or gown; the pelage or skin, of a single animal (head included) is generally used with street dress while for formal wear a finished length of fur using the skins of more than one animal is used; the word stole stands alone or is used in combination: fur stole, mink stole, the namesake of Dreamlander Mink Stole.

Until you provide context, for this American at least, it won't conjure any religious connotation. If you say that a *man* is wearing one, it will. These are different from *hijabs* (head scarfs), so even if you say a *women* is wearing one; still not 'religious'.

That being said, there's about three pages of text between those two quotes that are about religious items. But note that the semantic definition makes no mention of it. - *shawl* : "a simple item of clothing" that when worn by a woman, is called a *stole*.